# Pegasos prediction time

Tags: svm, algorithms

I have been implementing the (kernelized) Pegasos algorithm, but am running into problems in terms of scalability. I will use notations as in the [original manuscript](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~nati/Publications/PegasosMPB.pdf). Here's a typical time measurement:

```
percent         m   t1      t2
0.05%           32  701     961
0.1%            64  676     1890
0.2%            128 648     2777
0.41%           256 725     3851
0.83%           512 861     5267
1.67%           1024 1293    7635
3.34%           2048 1928    11404
6.68%           4096 3256    18210
13.36%          8192 6312    31750
26.72%          16384 11420   56923
53.44%          32768 18838   96755
```

Where $m$ is the number of data points in the training set, t1 the training time (includes cross validation over many folds) and t2 the testing time (just 1 prediction over a larger, but fixed part of the data).

As you can see, the train time scales reasonably well, but the prediction time scales very badly. I think this is due to the fact that the Pegasos algorithm requires one to compute the (kernel) product of every test-point with a large number of training inputs, that increases as the total training set ($m$) increases. Are there known ways to cope with this problem? I thought the L1-norm would take care of this problem due to sparsification of the model (#support vectors), but I don't think it does. I was thinking of simply dropping terms with low 'counts' ($\alpha$ value in Fig. 3 in the original manuscript), but that seems terribly unelegant ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prediction complexity is proportional to the amount of SVs and the complexity of kernel evaluation. Typically, the complexity of kernel evaluation is linear in terms of the number of input dimensions. The SVM decision function for a test instance $\mathbf{z}$ is as follows:

$$f(\mathbf{z}) = \sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}} \alpha_i y_i \kappa(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{z}) + b,$$

with $\alpha$ the dual weights, $\mathbf{y}$ the training labels, $\kappa(\cdot,\cdot)$ the kernel and $b$ a bias term. The prediction complexity scales linearly with the amount of SVs due to the sum of kernel evaluations (a consequence of the representer theorem).

Even though typical SV models are sparse (e.g. not all training instances become SVs), this can become problematic. For large data sets, the set of SVs tends to become large too, despite SVM's sparsity. Pruning SVs based on their corresponding weights is generally a bad idea, as is already mentioned in the OP.

This can be avoided for some kernels to make prediction complexity independent to the number of SVs, but not in general. Some examples:

- models using the **linear kernel** can be summarized as $f(\mathbf{z}) = \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{z}+b$ with $\mathbf{w} = \sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}} \alpha_i y_i \mathbf{x}_i$. $\mathbf{w}$ needs to be computed only once. This is one of the reasons linear models are so practical.
- models using an **RBF kernel** can be [approximated using a second-order Maclaurin series of the exponential function](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.0736.pdf). Using such an approximation, prediction complexity becomes quadratic in terms of the input dimensionality. The approximated decision function assumes a quadratic form $\tilde{f}(\mathbf{z}) = \mathbf{z}^T\mathbf{M}\mathbf{z} + \mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{z}+c$ in which $\mathbf{M}$, $\mathbf{v}$ and $c$ need to be computed once.
- models using **[additive kernels](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~smaji/papers/mbm2012pami.pdf)**.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer, Marc! I am going to try the Maclaurin approximation, since I am using an RBF kernel for my particular purpose.

Comment: @ciri you can find a free implementation of the approximation I referred to [here](https://github.com/claesenm/approxsvm).